# fluent nhibernate: INSERT error when saving a new entity with a child entity

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I am trying to save a new entity 'Post' with 1 item added to its 'Revisions' List.

A `Post` can have many `PostRevisions`, and a `PostRevision` can only have one `Post`.

I have tried several ways of mapping the PostRevisions, my PostRevisionMap is as follows:

```
 public PostRevisionMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.PostRevisionId, "PostRevisionId");
        Map(x => x.Created, "CreateDateTime").Not.Nullable();
       /// SOME OTHER STUFF HERE
        References(x => x.Post, "PostId"); // OPTION 1

        References(x => x.Post,"PostId").ForeignKey("PostId").PropertyRef(d => d.PostId);  // OPTION 2

        HasOne<Post>(x => x.Post).ForeignKey("PostId").Cascade.All().PropertyRef(x => x.PostId); // OPTION 3
    }
```

When calling SaveOrUpate I get a different errors

OPTION 1 & 3 cause

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "PostId".
```

OPTION 2 causes

```
NHibernate.HibernateException : Unable to resolve property: PostId
```

My PostMap is as follows:

```
   public PostMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.PostId).Column("PostId");

        HasMany(x => x.Revisions)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Table("PostRevisions")
            .KeyColumn("PostId")
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PostRevision_Post");

       /// OTHER STUFF
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as I can not spot the issue.
TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

PostMap

```
HasMany(x => x.Revisions)
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade.All();
```

PostRevisionMap:

```
References(x => x.Post);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but unfortunetly no joy.
Still get 
'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "PostId".'

PostId on the Post table is auto increment primary key. and that is where the error is coming from I think

Comment: Hmm...try this on PostMap: Id(x => x.PostId).GeneratedBy.Identity();

Comment: Spotted the problem, during my testing I had somehow generated a new one to one join between the two tables.

Thanks for your help/